# ¿Cómo saber cuando ha terminado un ciclo For Each?

Tags: vb.net, bucle-for

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que leerá archivos .xml de manera masiva y los ordenará en una hoja de Excel, para eso estoy usando un ciclo For Each

```
For Each mFile As String In openFile.FileNames
        documentoxml.load(IO.Path.GetFullPath(mFile))
        nomina12 = documentoxml.selectNodes("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Complemento/nomina12:Nomina")
        Select Case IO.Path.GetExtension(openFile.FileName.ToString).ToLower()
            Case ".xml"
                For Each nodo In nomina12
                    xlsWorkSheet.Cells(archivo, actual) = "Fecha inicial de pago"
                    Try
                        xlsWorkSheet.Cells(archivo + 1, actual) = (nodo.attributes.getNamedItem("FechaInicialPago").text)
                    Catch
                    End Try
                    actual = actual + 1
                    xlsWorkSheet.Cells(archivo, actual) = "Fecha final de pago"
                    Try
                        xlsWorkSheet.Cells(archivo + 1, actual) = (nodo.attributes.getNamedItem("FechaFinalPago").text)
                    Catch
                    End Try
                    actual = actual + 1
                    xlsWorkSheet.Cells(archivo, actual) = "Fecha de pago"
                    Try
                        xlsWorkSheet.Cells(archivo + 1, actual) = (nodo.attributes.getNamedItem("FechaPago").text)
                    Catch
                    End Try
                    actual = actual + 1
                    xlsWorkSheet.Cells(archivo, actual) = "Días pagados"
                    Try
                        xlsWorkSheet.Cells(archivo + 1, actual) = (nodo.attributes.getNamedItem("NumDiasPagados").text)
                    Catch
                    End Try
                    actual = actual + 1
                    xlsWorkSheet.Cells(archivo, actual) = "Total percepciones"
                    Try
                        xlsWorkSheet.Cells(archivo + 1, actual) = (nodo.attributes.getNamedItem("TotalPercepciones").text)
                    Catch
                    End Try
                    actual = actual + 1
                    xlsWorkSheet.Cells(archivo, actual) = "Total deducciones"
                    Try
                        xlsWorkSheet.Cells(archivo + 1, actual) = (nodo.attributes.getNamedItem("TotalDeducciones").text)
                    Catch
                    End Try
                    actual = actual + 1
                    xlsWorkSheet.Cells(archivo, actual) = "Total otros pagos"
                    Try
                        xlsWorkSheet.Cells(archivo + 1, actual) = (nodo.attributes.getNamedItem("TotalOtrosPagos").text)
                    Catch
                    End Try
                Next
                archivo = archivo + 2
                actual = actualsave
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next
    actual = actual + 1
    actualsave = actual
    archivo = 1
```

Es es uno de los ciclos, al terminar ese ciclo, la variable "archivo" me regresará a la columna "A" de Excel y seguirá escribiendo los datos dónde se quedo "actual". El problema es que al terminar ese ciclo, actual = a donde inicio el ciclo, ya que estoy trabajando a archivo por archivo, actualsave es para que los demás archivos sepan desde donde se debe escribir.
Lo que necesito saber es cuando sea el último ciclo, para que "actual" no se regrese a la posición de "actualsave"

Comment: Después de pensarlo mejor he decidido crear una variable "contador", la cual al finalizar cada proceso se quedará con el último valor, luego seteare la variable actual al valor de contador. Algo mal hecho, pero no encontré otro modo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes revisar si es el ultimo elemento con la función last

```
For Each mFile As String In openFile.FileNames
    If mFile Is openFile.FileNames.Last Then
        'Aqui puedes realizar alguna accion'
    End If
Next
```

Saludos!